# Search Keyword Query to list all team sites on SharePoint Online Highlighted Content WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, highlighted-content-web-part

I want to display all private Team-Sites on a Page in SharePoint Online

Can somebody help me to get the right custom query?

Kind regards from austria,

Helmut

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below query to list all team sites in Highlighted Content Web part:

```
(contentclass:"STS_Site")(SiteTemplate:"GROUP" OR SiteTemplate:"STS")
```